# Microcontroller for running Linux RTAI

Tags: microcontroller, embedded-systems, real-time

I'm a beginner in Robotics.

I'd like to ask what are the minimum/recommended specs for a microcontroller to run a real-time system such as Linux RTAI?

What is the popular microcontroller for running Linux RTAI?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to check first which architectures RTAI supports. The latest versions support only x86 and x86_64, with support for ARM lagging behind a couple versions. Some other architectures had been supported at some point in the past, but there hasn't been any activity on them for a very long time. That's the minimum specs for the microcontroller: having RTAI actually support it.